# How to use R's dplyr to group by date and then get the sum in several specific columns for each group?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, across

I have a large dataset from some content analysis, with documents from different dates and a large number of columns with "1" if the document contains a statement of particular Code type and "0" if it does not.

I would like to group these rows by the `Date` of the document and then sum the total number of each code (Code 1, Code 2 etc.) for each of these groups. I can't quite work out how to do this though...

```r
                                                    Document.name       Date Code 1 Code 2 Code 3 Code 4 Code 5 Code 6
1 10_03_29_Five states have responsibilities to administer Arctic 29/03/2010      0      0      0      0      0      0
2 10_03_29_Five states have responsibilities to administer Arctic 29/03/2010      0      0      0      0      0      0
3 10_05_27_Climate change seriously affects Arctic diversity repo 27/05/2010      0      0      0      0      0      0
4 10_05_27_Climate change seriously affects Arctic diversity repo 27/05/2010      0      0      0      0      0      0
5 10_05_27_Climate change seriously affects Arctic diversity repo 27/05/2010      0      0      0      0      0      0
6 10_05_27_Climate change seriously affects Arctic diversity repo 27/05/2010      0      0      1      0      0      0
```

I've tried:

```
test <- cn_leg %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(across(contains("Code"), sum),.groups = 'drop')  %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

but this produces the following error:

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(contains("Code"), sum)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Date = "01/02/2021".
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `Code`.
Caused by error:
! invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Could anybody help me out?

Reproducible example:

````
structure(list(Document.name = c("10_03_29_Five states have responsibilities to administer Arctic", 
"10_03_29_Five states have responsibilities to administer Arctic", 
"10_05_27_Climate change seriously affects Arctic diversity repo"
), Date = c("29/03/2010", "29/03/2010", "27/05/2010"), Code..3a..Input.fairness = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), Code..3a..Input.expert.leadership = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Code..3a..Input.participation = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), Code..3a..Input.leadership.characteristics = c(0L, 0L, 
0L), Code..3b.Output.Effectiveness..general. = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Code..3b.Output.Contribution.to.environment = c(0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Code..Contribution.to.environment.Contribution.to.environmental.issues = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Code..Contribution.to.environment.Contribution.to.climate.change = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example of your dataset? It looks like the issue is with the `across(contains("Code"), sum)` , but its hard to tell with out seeing the data.

Comment: @JoshWhite thanks for your reply. I've tried to add a small reproducible example of the data as I view it in R Studio.

Comment: It runs ok in my computer. Have you checked that the code columns are numeric?

Comment: @Santiago you don't get any error? When I do `class(cn_leg$Code..3a..Input.participation)` the result is "integer"

Comment: No error. This is the output `structure(list(Date = c("27/05/2010", "29/03/2010"), Code..3a..Input.fairness = c(0L, 
0L), Code..3a..Input.expert.leadership = c(0L, 0L), Code..3a..Input.participation = c(0L, 
0L), Code..3a..Input.leadership.characteristics = c(0L, 0L), 
    Code..3b.Output.Effectiveness..general. = c(0L, 0L), Code..3b.Output.Contribution.to.environment = c(0L, 0L), Code..Contribution.to.environment.Contribution.to.environmental.issues = c(0L, 0L), Code..Contribution.to.environment.Contribution.to.climate.change = 1:0), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")`.

Comment: @Santiago Thank you. That helped resolve it - was because I had another, non numeric column in the full dataset which also had "Code" in column name. It was trying to sum this column as well, and throwing up the error.